# ENOENT Error - no such file or directory, open 'package.json', when packaged from Electron Builder/Packager both

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

The app packages successfully but gives an ENOENT error on opening it.
After the app is written is the specified folder. On opening the Application file, an error is shown - 
**ENOENT : no such file or directory. open 'package.json'**

With Electron-Packager And Builder - 
I have tried a flat file structure as in electron-quick-start (main, package, index all in parent folder).

Also With Electron-Packager-
Tried recommended file structure as well (src/main, index).

The error is same via Electron Builder & Packager both.

The details are as follows -

Package.json & CLI : https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzVR6.png

Error when Application is opened : https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mRq4.png

The Basic version of Project can be tested here : [Downloadable Project](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1OBzvinbj1KEE9fKzFtHYv5beb5qa33IC&export=download)

---

**Solution**

The bug is because of Electron-DB : [here](https://github.com/alexiusacademia/electron-db/issues/18)

Comment: I would recommend re-trying with the example & command provided for [electron-packager](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager#example). Based on that, you're missing details on the `package.json` as well as on the command. Let us know if following the example resolves your issue!

Comment: I did try again, following the steps. But no luck. I just shared a basic project which can be tested. Please let me know if you review it and find any issues. I also tried adding asar explicitly as mentioned here - [Packager Issue](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/issues/892) . But it didnt help either.

Comment: The bug is because of Electron-DB and not Electron-Builder or Packager. Thanks

Comment: Nice find. You could post that as an answer & accept it. Also, just FYI - the most convenient way to share would be uploading the project to GitHub instead of sharing on Google Drive - makes it easier for people to contribute fixes, but if you are sharing a ZIP, just leave out the `node_modules` folder since its huge (fille size) & anyone trying it out on their end can just install & get the contents themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug is because of Electron-DB : [here](https://github.com/alexiusacademia/electron-db/issues/18)